# Deklination des Adjektivs

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending, interrogative

Ich habe den Satz:

> Welcher deutsche See ist am größten?

Warum ist es ‚deutsch**e**‘ und nicht ‚deutsch**er**‘?

Comment: related: [Same noun, same case, same adjective, different ending](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi) and perhaps [“Welcher kluge Mann!” vs. “Welch kluger Mann!”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/welcher-kluge-mann-vs-welch-kluger-mann)

Answer (score 1):

Die technische Antwort ist, dass es sich um [schwache Deklination](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:gro%C3%9F) handelt. Die einfache, aber unvollständige Antwort ist, dass „welcher“ bereits das „r“ hat und deshalb das Adjektiv keines mehr benötigt.

Comment: Ich habe das für das erste Mal gewusst, das war sehr nützlich, danke sehr

Answer (score 0):

```
Nominativ:

 Maskulin  Feminin   Neutrum    Plural
 --------  --------  ---------  --------
 welcher   welche    welches    welche
 deutsche  deutsche  deutsches  deutsche
```

Da *See* hier Nominativ maskulin singular ist, muss es heißen:

- *Welcher deutsche See …*
- *Welche deutsche Frau …*
- *Welches deutsche Mädchen …*
- *Welche deutsche(n) Firmen …*

Nur mit einem unbestimmten Artikel heißt es: *ein deutscher See*.

Comment: danke ,  mitt Dativ es wird ( deutschen ) immer , oder?

Comment: @a_barsa ja

http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Adjektiv.htm

Comment: Alles klar, vielen Dank.

Answer (score 0):

The declination of German adjectives is complicated. You can't expect sb to explain the full system here. That's a chapter in a grammar. - But to say it in a nutshell:

Welcher deutsche See

The word welcher has already a gender sign (-er, masculine), so this gender sign is not repeated a second time.